# Join in Doctrine not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I implemented Doctrine in CodeIgniter. I used entity classes PdContact and PdSubject and placed under Entity folder under model s folder. I used following code for joining the tables:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder('c')->select('PdContact')->leftJoin('PdSubject', 'co', 'WITH', 'co.id = c.id')->setMaxResults(20);

$query = $qb->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

But it is not working. Please give a suggestion.

Comment: What is not working? What is expected and what is the result? Do you have error messages?

Comment: just curious, why would you use Doctrine opposed to Codeigniter's query builder class ?

Comment: Have you mapped in Doctrine 2 relations?  If so then consider looking at the manual: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html.  Your query is missing the from clause.  In most cases, you won't need with in the left join.  DQL is not SQL.

Comment: I got the error as "Error: Identification Variable PdSubject used in join path expression but was not defined before"

Comment: One error message is shown as "Error: Class PdContact has no association named PdSubject'

Comment: I am new to doctrine. Please suggest how mapped in Doctrine 2 relations.